# systemd power key pressed at the same time every day

Tags: systemd, shutdown

I have encountered unexpected shutdowns on a microserver, and the logs indicate that they are caused by the **"Power key pressed"** event.

After conducting some research, it appears that this could potentially be a hardware problem. However, given that these shutdowns consistently occur at a specific time of day, I currently have strong doubts regarding it being a hardware issue.

Here's a `journalctl | grep Power key pressed`:

```
Jun 01 05:16:28 backup systemd-logind[1005]: Power key pressed.
Jun 01 05:16:28 backup systemd-logind[1005]: Power key pressed.
Jun 04 05:16:28 backup systemd-logind[982]: Power key pressed.
Jun 04 05:16:28 backup systemd-logind[982]: Power key pressed.
Jun 06 05:16:19 backup systemd-logind[982]: Power key pressed.
Jun 06 05:16:19 backup systemd-logind[982]: Power key pressed.
```

I guess *something* is requesting a shutdown? Any idea how I could figure out what? Can it be that the server gets too hot and requests a safe shutdown?

**Update:**

After some investigation I am now certain, that running a `restic` backup, that is copying files from one raid disk to another raid disk within the server is what is triggering the "Power key pressed" event.

At this point I think my question is: can the "Power key pressed" event be directly triggered by software or is it literally the power button circuit closing for sure?

Comment: `the server gets too hot` ... at about the same time (within 10 seconds) on 3 different days? (not every day like you suggested)

Comment: It could be a hardware issue in combination with a power grid fluctuation that happens at this time (e.g. additional plant startet to buffer extra power usage in the morning). Try disabling the pwoer key (no need on a server anyway .. in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` set `HandlePowerKey=ignore`)

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, it doesn't seem like a sane thing :)

Comment: @FelixJN what kind of hardware issue? like the powerbutton is slightly malfunctioning? I think I run a more power intensive operation at this time, it could be the extra poweruptake via the battery is too much?

Comment: I'll be vague here and speculate vividly: After all a button press means creating an electrical connection. Now the two electrodes near the button could be corroded and be in contact via this corrision material which itself could be a quite bad semiconductor. A voltage fluctuation on the grid (or extra uptake from battery as you say) now could be just enough to have a current flow between these electrodes and there is our *button pressed* signal.

Comment: @FelixJN thanks! I'll experiment a bit :)

Comment: One crazy debugging test : change the clock on your system by, say, 100 minutes. If it still happens at that time, it's a software issue. If it regularly happens 100 minutes earlier, it's something external (like the power grid fluctuations others have suggested)

Comment: Have you ruled out your server's IPMI/DRAC/iLO controller being the source of the shutdown request? (e.g. a runaway cronjob that calls ipmitool, or a power usage limit thing)

Comment: @u1686_grawity no, how would you do that?